# how shall i call out this function using string format method?

Tags: python, string, format-string

i'm learning Python and have began with Google's Python Automation Beginner course. Idk if i chose it right but im already in week 4 and now have started facing confusion.

Fill in the gaps in the nametag function so that it uses the format method to return first_name and the first initial of last_name followed by a period. For example, nametag("Jane", "Smith") should return "Jane S."

```
  def nametag(first_name, last_name):
return("___.".format(___))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return '{} {}.'.format(first_name, last_name[0])
```

will put the arguments of `format` in place of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an fstring. It's more modern (and easier to read) than format().
`f'{first_name} {last_name[0]}.'`

Comment: Where did you get this information that it's outdated?

Comment: Error on line 2:
    f'{first_name} {last_name[0]}.
                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You missed a ' at the end.

Comment: yes got that after seeing the carefully. Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return("{} {[0]}.".format(first_name,last_name))

print(nametag("Jane", "Smith")) 
print(nametag("Francesco", "Rinaldi")) 

print(nametag("Jean-Luc", "Grand-Pierre"))
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, consider adding an explanation of how and why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

def nametag(first_name, last_name):

```
return("{first_name} {last_name[0]}.".format(first_name= first_name, last_name=last_name[0]))
```

print(nametag("Jane", "Smith"))

## Should display "Jane S."

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):

    return "{} {last_name}.".format(first_name, last_name=last_name[0])


print(nametag("Jane", "Smith"))

out put:
Jane S.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return("{}{}{}.".format(first_name," ",last_name[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    name = '{}.{}'.format(first_name, last_name)
    location = name.find('.')
    name = name[:location + 2].replace('.', ' ') + '.'
    return name
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated. You could have added the space and the period in `{}.{}`.

Comment: This is just a different way of doing it opens many options to solve complicated qeries

Answer (score 0):

Correction: Here is a very simple solution that works

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return("{} {:.1}.".format(first_name, last_name))
print(nametag("Jane", "Smith"))
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining how this format syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
    return("{} {}.".format(first_name, last_name[0]))

print(nametag("Jane", "Smith")) 
# Should display "Jane S." 
print(nametag("Francesco", "Rinaldi")) 
# Should display "Francesco R." 
print(nametag("Jean-Luc", "Grand-Pierre")) 
# Should display "Jean-Luc G."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nametag(first_name, last_name):
return '{} {:>2s}.'.format(first_name, last_name[0])
```

you should use {:>2s} for the space between Jane and S
"followed by a period" in question.